# Springboot: Ribbon and Zuul

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

Do we need to configure both Ribbon and Zuul for Loadbalancing the microservices.

From what I have seen Zuul is more of a conventional reverse-proxy loadbalancer and any request to services thro Zuul will automatically be loadbalanced and I do not have to configure Ribbon in individual microservices.

We will need Ribbon configured in the service only if we need to connect to a service that is not proxied by Zuul.

Is the understanding correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eureka for discovering your services, that are balanced through zuul, you don't need to configure ribbon in any way.

Say, you have a `ServiceA` that is discovered by eureka and you have a zuul route configured like this one

```
 zuul:
   routes:
     example:
       path: /example/**
       serviceId: ServiceA
```

As soon as you have more than one instance of `ServiceA` running, zuul will start to load balance the load of all `ServiceA` with a round robin algorithm.